# What is the order of this group $G$ for the given relation?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is the group generated by the elements $x,y$ with the relations $$x^3=y^2=(xy)^2=1$$ Then how can I get the order of $G$?

Comment: It is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the relations hold for the elements $x=(1\,2\,3)$ and $y=(1\,2)$ of $S_3$ (which generate $S_3$). While this only shows that $S_3$ is a *quotient* of $G=\langle\,x,y\mid x^3=y^2=xyxy=1\,\rangle$, we readily suspect that the group is infact isomorphic to $S_3$. To verify this, note that all elements of $G$ can be written as $x^ky^m$ with $k\in\{0,1,2\}$, $m\in\{0,1\}$ because it is always possible to move $y$ across an $x$: $yx=x^{-1}y^{-1}=x^2y$.

Comment: By the way, it is just as easy to see that $x^n = y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1$ gives the dihedral group of order $2n$.